# Calling MVC Controller method with Ajax call not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call a ActionMethod from my controller for data doing an Ajax call but I can't seem to be able to reach it.

It works if I keep my javascript code in my html page but when I move my code to a dedicated js file the errors happen.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("getMessage")',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
    cache: false,
    success: function (type) {
        // data is your result from controller
        if (type.success) {
            languagedata = type.json;
            console.log(type);
            console.log(type.json);

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

I have already trying changing url to following and it still didn't work

```
    var url = '@Url.Action("getMessage", "Contract")';

  var url = '<%= Url.Action("getMessage", "Contract") %>',
```

I'm I doing something wrong?
My console gives error:
http://localhost:59474/@Url.Action(%22getMessage%22)?_=1540980518712 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Javascript doesn't know `@Url.Action`. paste actual url like `/Conract/` and try

Comment: Please check if the HTTPVerb on the method(Post or Get)

Comment: Razor code is not parsed in external js files. You need to use `@Url.Action()` in the main view and pass it to the script (e.g. by using a `data` attribute in the element you are handling, or just declaring a global variable in the main view

Comment: Hello what front_end_dev told me worked. But I will try to do what Stephen Muecke said because it seems to be to the cleanest way to do it. Thank you for the help